# How to Delete a Role ARN Assigned to a Cognito User Pool Group?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

When I first created a Cognito User Pool Group it had *no* Role ARN assigned to it.

I assigned a Role ARN to the group via the "Update group" dialog.

How do I remove/delete the Role ARN I just assigned?  It doesn't look like it's possible from the AWS console.

I've attached an image with the field in question.

[image: A Role ARN assigned to a Cognito group]

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same situation.

First thing I tried was to create a role called "dummy" with just authorization to lambda function, then i switched to that role (just like the screenshot you shared).
Then I deleted the role to test and see if the group would then have an unselected role but it still showed "dummy" as the role selected.

I don't really understand why it still had the supposedly deleted role but I ended up deleting the group and recreating it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you cannot even delete it programmatically using AWS SDK.

The best you can do is to create a dummy role with no permissions at all and set it to this dummy role's ARN.

I believe it is a bug in the AWs API.